# Use .Net Assembly Generated by Matlab inside Winform Application

Tags: .net, winforms, matlab

I have an algorithm developed by using Matlab. I need to build a C# desktop application around it. So I used Matlab compiler generated a .Net Assembly from it. And the Assembly works pretty well inside my console test application. Then I tried to do the same thing inside my Winform application and get a quite ambiguous exception when constructing the matlab object. Does anyone has similar experience? Why the assembly behaviour in such way? Thanks.

Comment: I've read your question multiple times and I still can't understand it ... I don't think many people can. You should edit your post to give more details (do not add details in comments please).

Comment: Please show the code of constructing matlab object and the exception. Help others recreate the error so they can start investigation.

Comment: I know what's going on now. The assembly actually is generated by my client. And I noticed it can only work with x64 build. And I did so for both console test app and the winform app (solution platform shows x86). But it appears that the target platform for the winform app project is still x86. It works after I changed it into x64.